# MPSA42 confusion

Tags: bjt, nixie

i want to drive my nixie clock with mpsa42, but i am confused about wiring diagram.
I found one with Base resistor and one without it. From some sources i found that mpsa42, is digital BJT,
but from its datasheet it´s not very clear for me
Link to Datasheet of mpsa42: https://cz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/258/MPSA42_7eMPSA43(TO-92)-1626582.pdf
[image]

[image]

Edit: i wanted to drive it like this: [image]

Comment: MPSA42 is a "ordinary" BJT. Thus, you need to add an external base current limiting resistor.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331220/anode-driver-for-nixie-clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPSA-42 is NOT a "digital" transistor in the sense that that is normally meant.
It does not include a base resistor on the package - this must be provided externally if required.

A base drive resistor will be required in all common emitter circuits.

Please provide a copy of your circuit and / or a link to the circuit you intend to use.
Usually the MPSA42 emitter will be grounded, the base will be driven via a resistor and collector will connect to a positive high voltage load.

---

Added:

Any BJT with a base drive resistor becomes a "digital transistor".
Any FET is a "digital transistor"

[Here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?FV=mu1000V%7C2068%2Cmu1050V%7C2068%2Cmu1100V%7C2068%2Cmu1200V%7C2068%2Cmu1400V%7C2068%2Cmu1500V%7C2068%2Cmu1700V%7C2068%2Cmu2000V%7C2068%2Cmu2200V%7C2068%2Cmu2500V%7C2068%2Cmu3000V%7C2068%2Cmu300V%7C2068%2Cmu330V%7C2068%2Cmu350V%7C2068%2Cmu4000V%7C2068%2Cmu400V%7C2068%2Cmu415V%7C2068%2Cmu4500V%7C2068%2Cmu450V%7C2068%2Cmu4700V%7C2068%2Cmu480V%7C2068%2Cmu500V%7C2068%2Cmu520V%7C2068%2Cmu525V%7C2068%2Cmu530V%7C2068%2Cmu550V%7C2068%2Cmu560V%7C2068%2Cmu600V%7C2068%2Cmu620V%7C2068%2Cmu640V%7C2068%2Cmu650V%7C2068%2Cmu700V%7C2068%2Cmu750V%7C2068%2Cmu800V%7C2068%2Cmu850V%7C2068%2Cmu900V%7C2068%2Cmu950V%7C2068%2C-8%7C278&quantity=10&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&k=mosfet&pageSize=25&pkeyword=mosfet) is a Digikey list of FETS with Vds >= 300V in 10 quantity.
The lowest cost [AO3162](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3162.pdf) is rated at 600CV at 34 mA for $US0.28 in 10 quantity.
The [IDP50R3KOCEA...](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/IPx50R3K0CE_2_0.pdf?folderId=db3a3043163797a6011637d4bae7003b&fileId=db3a304339dcf4b10139e7e9ff592ce4) is rated at 500V at 1.7A and cost $US0.35 in 10 quantity

Comment: Thank you for quick response, can you suggest me some cheap digital BJT or mosfet that i can drive from cmos logic and have breakdown voltage over 250mA?

Comment: @JakubProchazka nobody can suggest what you ask for because it is illogical.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, I mean 250V.

Comment: @JakubProchazka See addition to my answer