# Nixie anode transistor dimmer

Tags: transistors, esp32, dimming, nixie

I'm working on my nixie clock (IN-14) and I am stucked on one problem.
When I tried to dim my nixie tube through transistor on cathode, everything works fine.
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7KPsxm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But unfortunately I can't have transistor to dim the nixie tube, because I'm using nixie controller, so I can put transistor only on anode, but it does not work as I wished.

I would like to try something like this, which was recommended [there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331220/anode-driver-for-nixie-clock)

but unfortunately, I don't know which resistor should I use between transistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fokvEcm.png)</sup>

Comment: The 2N5551 is rated for 160 V VCE and you're using it on a 170 V rail?  Are you PWM dimming? What's your PWM frequency?

Comment: Yes, I am using PWM for dimming. I am using ESP32 with AnalogWrite library, which use in default 5000 Hz PWM frequency.
Yes, I am using 2N5551, in eshop of my seller, there is information that it can handle 180V, but if 170V is really limit, I can buy another one according to your recommendation

Comment: In general for long life, it is best practice to *double* whatever rating you are specifying; i.e. if you need a 25V capacitor, pick 50V.  0.5W resistor, pick 1W (at least.)  170V transistor, well they do make these in 400V+ but they are less common.  That way the components are not "running at the edge of failure" but with a significant safety margin.

Answer (score 1):

The output transistor (when on) is not saturated and we don't care much if it has a few volts across it so we can use the hFE value from the transistor datasheet.

I will assume the nixie anode current is no more than 2mA, adjust accordingly if yours is different.

If you use [MPSA42](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mpsa42-d.pdf) NPN transistors, the hFE at 10V Vce and 1mA is at least 25. So with 9V across the resistor the base current should be >80uA, which means around 100K is about right.

Possibly overly cautious, but without further investigation I would also put a reverse-biased 1N4148 from base to emitter on the high side transistor.

---

Edit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fISV1v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you make a little schema of circuit for me? I am not sure if I understand that properly.
And yes, IN-14 is using 2.5mA for digit and 0.3mA for point, so there is chance, that it can takes around 2.8mA (accoring to this datasheet [link](http://www.tube-tester.com/sites/nixie/data/in-14/in-14.htm))

Comment: See edit. 100K should be okay.

Comment: I already tested your solution and it works pretty good. You have my thanks! :)