# How can I add variable duty cycle PWM to a CircuitLab simulation within a question?

Tags: pwm, duty-cycle, circuitlab

This is my first attempt to simulate a circuit in the time domain with CircuitLab. In order to ask a proper question about something similar driven with PWM, I'd like to add an adjustable duty cycle to the square wave, and then if possible ramp it.

How can I add variable duty cycle PWM to a CircuitLab simulation within a question?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fprajz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: So far I haven't found anything in meta that discusses if CircuitLab assistance is off-topic, nor have I found anything in the help center for or against. Further, my previous question [How to approximate the behavior of a phototransistor in the circuit editor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/293774/102305) was answered without incident. Why the *silent, anonymous insta-close* vote rather than a helpful comment?

Comment: As long as we're talking about CircuitLab *in general* and not a detail of the StackExchange implementation, it's fine on the main site (instead of meta.EE)

Comment: @W5VO thanks! Yep this one's strictly about simulating a circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I've never had to do it but this might work for you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f81KiC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two sawtooth oscillators and a comparator.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Note the DC offset in the sawtooth configuration.*

[image]

*Figure 3. The result.*

I seem to have configured the amplitude incorrectly on the triangle waves. They should probably be 2.5 V with 2.5 V offset but perhaps the graph is clearer like this.

Comment: Oh excellent! Yes I've got the idea, this will work nicely. It may in fact be how it was actually done at some point.